# Spring Reactive Test cases

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have been trying to write a unit test case for a Spring Reactive module. I am facing errors in that module.

Here is my test case code:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.AutoConfigureWebTestClient;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;
import org.springframework.test.web.reactive.server.WebTestClient;


@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest(CustomController.class)
@AutoConfigureWebTestClient
public class CustomControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebTestClient testClient;

    @Test
    public void broadcastVoltageConsumption() {
        System.out.println("CONTEXT LOADING >>>>>>>>>");
        System.out.println(testClient);
    }
}
```

I am getting following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to find a @SpringBootConfiguration, you need to use @ContextConfiguration or @SpringBootTest(classes=...) with your test

    at org.springframework.util.Assert.state(Assert.java:73)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.getOrFindConfigurationClasses(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:240)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:153)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.web.reactive.WebFluxTestContextBootstrapper.processMergedContextConfiguration(WebFluxTestContextBootstrapper.java:35)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:395)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildDefaultMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:312)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildMergedContextConfiguration(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:265)
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(AbstractTestContextBootstrapper.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.buildTestContext(SpringBootTestContextBootstrapper.java:97)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:139)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.<init>(TestContextManager.java:124)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTestContextManager(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:151)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.<init>(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:142)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner.<init>(SpringRunner.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:49)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

While another class with main method has the same configuration it works fine.

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebFluxTest
public class SpringWebFluxDemoApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
        System.out.println("CONTEXT LOAD ########## ");
    }

}
```

Not able to figure out what is wrong here, any help on this?

Comment: Are both test classes (SpringWebFluxDemoApplicationTests and CustomControllerTest) in the same package?

Comment: No, they are in different packages SpringWebFluxDemoApplicationTests is in org.opensource.springwebflxudemo.main and CustomControllerTest is in org.opensource.springwebflxudemo.controller

Comment: I believe there is a difference in configuration for SpringWebFluxDemoApplication and CustomController (there is something missing in CustomController, which is already in SpringWebFluxDemoApplication class).

Comment: Both are as I have shown in the code. that is the reason I am not getting why it is not working.

Comment: I believe that Spring test does not see the main class and can't start application. Can you try to move everything from "org.opensource.springwebflxudemo.main"  to parent "org.opensource.springwebflxudemo" package? (Or, at least, SpringWebFluxDemoApplication class)